# Is it possible to create an SQL Server Azure VM but use your own license?

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine

I have a program that is a .net console app that is intended to track information at a few websites daily and then put this data into an SQL database.

Previously I've had this program running on a scheduler on my computer but I'm about to take off on a 3 month vacation so I'm planning on deploying it on azure to run it while I'm away.

Last night I set up a SQL server VM. I got it all set up then I tracked the pricing and realized that using the SQL Server image increased the price by about 30$ per month compared to the Windows image (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines)

I have an SQL Server license. So I was thinking of just setting up a Windows VM and then installing SQL server on it. THe only problem is that I'm going to have to copy the MSI over and install it etc. - it would take ages.

Is it possible to just create an SQL Server VM in azure and then enter my own license in there to avoid paying the extra 30$ per month?

By the way, is there a more economical way to get Azure to do this then using a VM? Really, it just needs to run daily and performance doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: you can only utilise your own SQL Server license on an Azure VM if your organisation's agreement with Microsoft includes License Mobility (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/license-mobility/).  If your are unsure or believe this is not the case then you cannot deploy your own license.  This is exactly the same on Amazon Web Services (AWS).

SQL Databases for Azure Mobile Services that are under 20MB are free - that may be an option depending on your needs. (see point 5 on this page: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the .NET console application to Worker Role (PAAS) and use Web Edition of SQL Database (PAAS), and recalculate your TCO.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can start with the SQL Server Trial image, then apply your own license on it (as on any trial installation).
2. You could also have a free Azure Web Site, with your code triggered as a "web job". For DB, there is a 20MB free tier for Azure SQL Database.

Comment: where is the SQL Server trial image?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a SQL Azure DB. They are only $4.95/mo for DB's under 100MB http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

Saves the entire headache of running your own SQL Server.

**Update: SQL Azure now has different pricing**

As suggested in the comments, use Azure WebJobs and if possible a free SQL DB if you only have very limited data to track operation.

Under 20Mb free

~$5/mo for up to 2GB

More Details: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

Comment: but then can I just schedule a .net app to run daily on that though?

Comment: A SQL Azure DB is just the database, you will need to get a VM as well. I assume you would only need a small one, hence ~$15/mo. You then just enter the connection string to the SQL DB in your app. You can still also use SSMS to connect to your SQL DB to administer it.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the scheduled tasks, you *might* be able to use a Windows Azure Web Job (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx) combined with the WA Scheduler (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) to cover it.

Comment: I love the WA Scheduler, using it extensively myself. I am assuming diskdrive just wants to throw a console app and task schedule it while he is away on holiday. But if he is wanting to do it properly, WA Scheduler is the way to go.

Comment: @downvoter - again its great to state a reason why so I can either improve my answer or delete it if completely incorrect. Just to let others know the pricing structure of SQL Azure has changed. Updated my answer.